# How to return to previous URL after clicking on "Back" button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I'm using simple_calendar in my Ruby on Rails project and I'm having a problem.

When I see "February" my URL looks like this:

```
localhost:3000/meetings?start_date=2016-02-07
```

After I "Edit" an event, I am redirected to the "Show" page of that event where I have a "Back" button.
When pressing that button, I'd like to return to the same month's URL I was at before. Instead of that, I return to:

```
localhost:3000/meetings
```

How do I return to the first URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`request.referer`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/referer) as the URL for the "Back" button.

Comment: I originally used this, but changed to `url_for(:back)` instead. This handles the edge case of user refreshing the page they landed on.

Answer (score 7):

This worked like a charm:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', url_for(:back) %>
```